# How to set Linux capabilities on docker swarm mode service invocations

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm looking into the notion of vault running under swarm (1.12.x).

A single container would be started with:
`docker run -d --cap-add IPC_LOCK -p 8200:8200 -p 8215:8125 --name vault --volume /vagrant/vault:/vagrant/vault vault server -config=/path/to/vault.hcl`

but when I want to run this in swarm as a service, there appears to be no way to specify the `IPC_LOCK` capability, in order to lock down encrypted swapping for the vault service in this case.

How can I set --cap-add flags when starting a swarm mode service with the `docker service create` command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of 20.10, this is available from `docker service create` with `--cap-add`:

```
$ docker service create --help
...
      --cap-add list                       Add Linux capabilities
      --cap-drop list                      Drop Linux capabilities
```

Or in a compose file used with `docker stack deploy` with the same syntax from the version 2 file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    image: your-image:tag
    cap_add:
    - CAP_NAME1
    - CAP_NAME2
    cap_drop:
    - CAP_NAME3
    - CAP_NAME4
```

---

[ Original answer from before 20.10 ]

It's currently not supported, but Docker is working on a solution. The logic behind not including the `--cap-add` option blindly is in a large cluster, there could be security concerns of a manager submitting containers with added privileges to a worker. The worker may trust running secure containers that can't access the host, but not want to allow remote root access to the host via a privileged container.

Discussion on this is over on github at:

https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26849#issuecomment-252704844

https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1030

https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/pull/1722

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25885#issuecomment-557790402 and https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2199

Answer (score 9):

All of the other answers here are old. Docker **20.10.0 and newer** now supports specifying capabilities for Swarm services via the [`docker service` command line](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/) and the [Docker Stack YAML file format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#cap_add-cap_drop).

On the command line, you just specify `--cap-add [capability]` or `--cap-drop [capability]`.

And here is an example for adding a capability in a Docker Stack YAML file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  your-service:
    cap_add:
      - CAP_SYS_ADMIN
```

Comment: This is good to know, but also keep in mind that 19.03.x is still widely used and will be for many years due to its use in various long-term supported distros.

Comment: I'm interested to know if I should - at some point - change the 'correct answer' when the same q is answered with a more recent version of the software in mind (that 'most' people use)

Comment: The main pull request confirms this information https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2687 but unfortunately, the official docker-compose file reference doesn't document this improvement yet and still indicates that cap_add and cap_drop are not supported in swarm mode.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to solve the problem and I can use `cap_net_admin` in swarm mode.

You can modify the runtime source code to add the capabilities that you need (it will be a local default setting).

For example I added the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` to my runtime (used `nvidia-container-runtime`)
[wanyvic/nvidia-container-runtime](https://github.com/wanyvic/nvidia-container-runtime/blob/master/runtime/runc/69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340/0001-add-nvida-container-runtime-hook-add-default-cap_net.patch).

After that I rebuilt it, started a container (use swarm mode), input: `capsh --print` and  CAP_NET_ADMIN  can be found:

```
root@25303a54ebb3:/# capsh --print
Current:=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap+eip
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=
```

But this method is not good.

I also can't set `cap_add` or `cap_drop` in `docker-compose.yml`, but I can't find a way to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

See https://hub.docker.com/r/ixdotai/swarm-launcher

That repo is based on this comment/idea: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25885#issuecomment-573355530

> Depending on the use case, a workaround is to bind-mount `/var/run/docker.sock` from the swarm host(s) to the service, then run `docker run --privileged ...` or `docker run --cap-add ...` from the service for executing your actual privileged commands. (You’ll have to install docker cli in the image for the service.) The innermost container that you docker run in this way will have the privileges/capabilities of the swarm host rather than of the service, and the service just becomes a thin container layer.